# Не присваивается значение

Tags: golang

Разбераюсь с golang и очень путаюсь в указателях.

```
type Transition struct {
    ID           string
    InitialState *State
    CurrentState *State
    Input        string
    Output       string
    Stimul       *int
}

func (t *Transition) SetStimul(stimul int) {
    t.Stimul = &stimul
}

func (sm StateMachine) Fill() StateMachine {
    sort.Sort(sm)
    i := 0
    for _, t := range sm {
        if t.InitialState.code == nil {
            t.InitialState.SetCode(i)
            i++
        }
    }
    // сигналы выозбуждения
    for _, t := range sm {
        t.SetStimul(*t.InitialState.code)
    }
    return sm
}
```

Изменяю значение указателя Transition.Stimul (изначально было nil), но отображается все равно nil (последний столбец).

```
2   A1  A2  00000   00001   <nil>
3   A2  A3  00001   00010   <nil>
4   A3  A4  00010   00011   <nil>
5   A4  A5  00011   00100   <nil>
6   A5  A6  00100   00101   <nil>
7   A5  A1  00100   00000   <nil>
8   A6  A7  00101   00110   <nil>
9   A7  A8  00110   00111   <nil>
10  A8  A9  00111   01000   <nil>
11  A9  A10 01000   01001   <nil>
12  A10 A11 01001   01010   <nil>
13  A11 A12 01010   01011   <nil>
14  A12 A13 01011   01100   <nil>
15  A13 A14 01100   01101   <nil>
16  A14 A15 01101   01110   <nil>
17  A15 A16 01110   01111   <nil>
18  A15 A16 01110   01111   <nil>
19  A16 A17 01111   10000   <nil>
20  A16 A17 01111   10000   <nil>
21  A17 A18 10000   10001   <nil>
22  A18 A19 10001   10010   <nil>
23  A19 A20 10010   10011   <nil>
24  A20 A21 10011   10100   <nil>
25  A21 A22 10100   10101   <nil>
26  A22 A23 10101   10110   <nil>
28  A23 A14 10110   01101   <nil>
29  A23 A14 10110   01101   <nil>
30  A24 A25 10111   11000   <nil>
31  A25 A26 11000   11001   <nil>
32  A26 A21 11001   10100   <nil>
```

Что я делаю не правильно?

Полный код: https://play.golang.org/p/a1874uZafs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напишите `type StateMachine []*Transition`
тогда `t.SetStimul()` будет менять элементы `StateMachine`.